# How would I perform quantile() of a sub-list within a list in R?

Tags: r, list, indexing, sublist, quantile

I have a `biglist`that contains 0 sublists, each of which are `List of 1`.

When I do `>biglist` I get this:

```
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]   
LIST1       Numeric,6  Numeric,6  Numeric,6  Numeric,6  Numeric,6  Numeric,6  Numeric,6  Numeric,6
```

Each sub-list contains both integer values and NA values. i.e.

`>biglist[1]` yields

> NA 0.50   NA   NA 0.25 1.00   NA 0.00`

`>biglist[2]` yields

> 0.500 0.375 0.000 0.500    NA 0.500 0.500    NA

And so on. I'm trying to find the 50th percentile and 95th percentile of all of the integer values of the sublists, but I want to get rid of the `NA` values. How would I accomplish this?

EDIT: Reproducible example
`biglist <- list(c(NA, 0.5, NA, NA, 0.25, 1, NA, 0), c(0.5, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA), c(0.5, 0.375, 0, 0.5, NA, 0.5, 0.5, NA), c(NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 0.5, 0.333333333333333), c(NA, NA, 0.125, NA,0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5), c(0.5, 0.25, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5), c(0.625,NA, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(0.25, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, NA,0.333333333333333), c(0.25, 0.75, NA, 0.5, 0.5, NA, 0, NA), c(NA,NA, 0.375, NA, 0.5, 0.5, 1, NA))`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Answer (score 1):

use `lapply` or `sapply` as follows

```
sapply(biglist, quantile, prob=c(.50, .95), na.rm=TRUE )
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]    [,7]     [,8] [,9] [,10]
# 50% 0.375  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5 0.56250 0.333333  0.5 0.500
# 95% 0.925  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.9  0.5 0.61875 0.483333  0.7 0.925

sapply(biglist, quantile, prob=c(.50, .95), na.rm=TRUE, simplify=FALSE )
# [[1]]
#   50%   95% 
# 0.375 0.925 

# [[2]]
# 50% 95% 
# 0.5 0.5 

# [[3]]
# 50% 95% 
# 0.5 0.5 

# [[4]]
# 50% 95% 
# 0.5 0.5 

# [[5]]
# 50% 95% 
# 0.5 0.9 

# [[6]]
# 50% 95% 
# 0.5 0.5 

# [[7]]
#     50%     95% 
# 0.56250 0.61875 

# [[8]]
#      50%      95% 
# 0.333333 0.483333 

# [[9]]
# 50% 95% 
# 0.5 0.7 

# [[10]]
#   50%   95% 
# 0.500 0.925
```